# DOMPDF - Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted

Tags: php, dompdf

I am getting the following error when try to create a PDF file with domPDF.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1800 bytes) in C:\AppServ\www\tpe\reportes\dompdf\include\line_box.cls.php on line 83
```

Do somebody know why and what can I do and why this problem is coming up?

This is part of the PHP code:

```
require_once("../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $html = stripslashes($html);
        $old_limit = ini_set("memory_limit", "16M");
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait'); //landscape , portrait
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("TPE - Reporte F.E.A. $asignaturashort.pdf");       
        exit(0);
        }
```

I already tried increasing "memory limit" up to 24M but is seems not having effect.

Comment: How did you try increasing the memory limit?

Comment: Ummm. because what you're doing requires more than 16 meg? Might as well be asking why water spills out of your glass when you fill it past the rim.

Comment: A changes the line: "memory_limit", "16M") --> "memory_limit", "24M")

Answer (score 1):

DOMPDF will take a lot of memory depending on the HTML you are trying to convert. Propably more than 24M. First try with the highest you can give for memory. Also make sure you have the latest version.

If this doesn't work, you might have to find another solution for your problem.

Comment: I did both. Increase to 24MB. And I also have latest version. My html has many lines, but I am using bigger html information. Maybe table lines are too much. Lines around 20, and columns around 30.

Comment: Well I am not sure. I look at phpinfo. I move the memory up to 64MB and it worked! thanks!